# Nodejs http proxy 'ECONNRESET'

Tags: node.js, http-proxy

I am trying to create a Nodejs proxy server that cycles through i.p. addresses in a JSON config file until it finds a working server. When running the application I get 'ECONNRESET'

The following is the code:

```
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');
var config = require('./config.json');

var debugging = 0;

var regex_hostport = /^([^:]+)(:([0-9]+))?$/;

function getHostPortFromString( hostString, defaultPort ) {
  var host = hostString;
  var port = defaultPort;

  var result = regex_hostport.exec( hostString );
  if ( result !== null ) {
    host = result[1];
    if ( result[2] !== null ) {
      port = result[3];
    }
  }

  return( [ host, port ] );
}
// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Begin: get new host >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
function getNewProxyHost( path, hostport, userRequest ){

    var options = {
            host : hostport[0],
            port: hostport[1],
            path: path,
            rejectUnauthorized: false
    };
    // have to extract the path from the requested URL

    var s = path.split("/",2);
    s = s[1];
    for ( var state in config ){
        if ( s == state ){
            // poll jurisdiction hosts to find active url
           var hosts = config[s];
           options.method = userRequest.method;
           options.headers = userRequest.headers;
           options.path = path.substring( 3, path.length );
           options.host = hosts[ 0 ].host;
           options.port = hosts[ 0 ].port;

           var tmpHost = hosts.shift();
           hosts.push( tmpHost );    

           return options;
        }
        else{
            // No jurisdiction provided GOTO : SOME DEFAULT PAGE?
            console.log( 'No jurisdiction provided in request.' );

        }
    }
}
// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<End: get new host<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
// handle a HTTP proxy request
function httpUserRequest( userRequest, userResponse ) {

  if ( debugging ) {
    console.log( '  > request: %s', userRequest.url );
  }

  //var httpVersion = userRequest.httpVersion;  // NOT read
  var path = userRequest.url;
  var hostport = getHostPortFromString( userRequest.headers.host, 443 );

  //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> set new host >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  options = getNewProxyHost( path, hostport, userRequest );
  console.log( '[ host: ',options.host, ' ]', '[ port: ', options.port, ' ]', '[ path: ', options.path, ' ]' );
  /*
  result = /^[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/[^\/]+(\/.*)?$/.exec( userRequest.url );
  if ( result ) {
    if ( result[1].length > 0 ) {
      path = result[1];
    } else {
      path = "/";
    }
  }
  */

  if ( debugging ) {
    console.log( '  > options: %s', JSON.stringify( options, null, 2 ) );
  }

  var proxyRequest = http.request(
    options,
    function ( proxyResponse ) {
      if ( debugging ) {
        console.log( '  > request headers: %s', JSON.stringify( options.headers, null, 2 ) );
      }

      if ( debugging ) {
        console.log( '  < response %d headers: %s', proxyResponse.statusCode, JSON.stringify( proxyResponse.headers, null, 2 ) );
      }

      userResponse.writeHead(
        proxyResponse.statusCode,
        proxyResponse.headers
      );

      proxyResponse.on(
        'data',
        function (chunk) {
          if ( debugging ) {
            console.log( '  < chunk = %d bytes', chunk.length );
          }
          userResponse.write( chunk );
        }
      );

      proxyResponse.on(
        'end',
        function () {
          if ( debugging ) {
            console.log( '  < END' );
          }
          userResponse.end();
        }
      );
    }
  );

  proxyRequest.on(
    'error',
    function ( error ) {
      //userResponse.writeHead( 500 );
      /*
      userResponse.write(
        "<h1>500 Error</h1>\r\n" +
        "<p>Error was <pre>" + error + "</pre></p>\r\n" +
        "</body></html>\r\n"
       );
       */
      console.log( 'Server Connection Error: ', error, ' \r\n',
              'headers ', options.headers, '\n',
              'host: ', options.host, '\n',
              'port: ', options.port, '\n',
              'path: ', options.path, '\n');

      proxyRequest.connection.destroy();
      // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> REDO proxy request >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
      httpUserRequest( userRequest, userResponse );    
    }
  );

  userRequest.on(
    'data',
    function (chunk) {
      if ( debugging ) {
        console.log( '  > chunk = %d bytes', chunk.length );
      }
      proxyRequest.write( chunk );
    }
  );

  userRequest.on(
    'end',
    function () {
      proxyRequest.end();
    }
  );
}

function main() {
  var port = 5556; // default port if none on command line

  // check for any command line arguments
  for ( var argn = 2; argn < process.argv.length; argn++ ) {
    if ( process.argv[argn] === '-p' ) {
      port = parseInt( process.argv[argn + 1] );
      argn++;
      continue;
    }

    if ( process.argv[argn] === '-d' ) {
      debugging = 1;
      continue;
    }
  }

  if ( debugging ) {
    console.log( 'server listening on port ' + port );
  }

  // start HTTP server with custom request handler callback function
  var server = http.createServer( httpUserRequest ).listen(port);

  // add handler for HTTPS (which issues a CONNECT to the proxy)
  server.addListener(
    'connect',
    function ( request, socketRequest, bodyhead ) {
      var url = request.url;
      var httpVersion = request.httpVersion;

      var hostport = getHostPortFromString( url, 443 );

      if ( debugging )
        console.log( '  = will connect to %s:%s', hostport[0], hostport[1] );

      // set up TCP connection
      var proxySocket = new net.Socket();
      proxySocket.connect(
        parseInt( hostport[1] ), hostport[0],
        function () {
          if ( debugging )
            console.log( '  < connected to %s/%s', hostport[0], hostport[1] );

          if ( debugging )
            console.log( '  > writing head of length %d', bodyhead.length );

          proxySocket.write( bodyhead );

          // tell the caller the connection was successfully established
          socketRequest.write( "HTTP/" + httpVersion + " 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n" );
        }
      );

      proxySocket.on(
        'data',
        function ( chunk ) {
          if ( debugging )
            console.log( '  < data length = %d', chunk.length );

          socketRequest.write( chunk );
        }
      );

      proxySocket.on(
        'end',
        function () {
          if ( debugging )
            console.log( '  < end' );

          socketRequest.end();
        }
      );

      socketRequest.on(
        'data',
        function ( chunk ) {
          if ( debugging )
            console.log( '  > data length = %d', chunk.length );

          proxySocket.write( chunk );
        }
      );

      socketRequest.on(
        'end',
        function () {
          if ( debugging )
            console.log( '  > end' );

          proxySocket.end();
        }
      );

      proxySocket.on(
        'error',
        function ( err ) {
          socketRequest.write( "HTTP/" + httpVersion + " 500 Connection error\r\n\r\n" );
          if ( debugging ) {
            console.log( '  < ERR: %s', err );
          }
          socketRequest.end();
          // Initiate new socket request with next relative proxy in table
        }
      );

      socketRequest.on(
        'error',
        function ( err ) {
          if ( debugging ) {
            console.log( '  > ERR: %s', err );
          }
          proxySocket.end();
        }
      );
    }
  ); // HTTPS connect listener
}

main();
```

Comment: Did you have any success getting this to work? I'm trying to do something similar with no luck.

Comment: I'd be interested in a solution as well...

Comment: I did get this to work, however the reason I was getting this error was because the project had two different versions of the API on the backend expecting two different forms of input. One worked and the other didn't.